# What is an Assoc. Bonus?

Tags: support

I'm curious what the Assoc Bonus is for.  In the future where can I look up this kind of information?  Am I right to ask about it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Association Bonus is awarded when you join a new Stackexchange network site if you have earned 200 reputation or more at any single other Stackexchange network site.

Since you have earned a nice chunk of reputation in your time here, you are automatically entitled to 100 bonus starting reputation at all other Stackexchange sites.  This is because you are now presumed to be somewhat familiar with the format, and therefore no longer need to earn the most basic privileges for each site (e.g. meta participation, ability to post images or multiple hyperlinks, interacting with "protected" questions, upvoting, flagging, chat, and a few [others](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/privileges) (note that privilege reputation requirements are reduced for us since we are still a beta site).

Details can be found in our [faq, under the reputation section](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).